# regex fails with dollar sign

Tags: r, regex, grepl

In R, I'm trying to match a series of strings from a vector of file names. I only want those without letters that end with .tif

```
allfiles <- c("181129_16_00_class_mlc.tif", "181129_16_00.tif.aux.xml", "181129_17_00_01_19.tif", "181129_17_00_01_20.tif", "181129_17_00_01_23.tif", "181129_17_00_01_24.tif", "181129_17_00_01_25.tif", "181129_17_00_01_26.tif", "181129_17_00_01_27.tif", "181129_17_00_01_28.tif", "181129_17_00_01_29.tif", "181129_17_00_01_30.tif")

 grepl("^[0-9_]+[.tif]", allfiles)
 grepl("^[0-9_]+[.tif]$", allfiles)
```

That returns:

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Why does the dollar sign fail? The result I expected from the second grepl was:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Sorry, typo, here you go.

Comment: Should that be `[.tif]+$`? Or just `\.tif$`?

Comment: "^[0-9_]+\\.tif$" works (double backlash is needed), but I still don't understand why [.tif]$ fails.

Comment: `[.tif]` means "one of any of the characters `.`, `t`, `i`, or `f`." That's not what you're trying to express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `$` what fails but the usage of brackets. Instead you want

```
grepl("^[0-9_]+\\.tif$", allfiles)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Meanwhile, `^[0-9_]+[.tif]$` means that after all the digits and/or _, at the end you just have t, i, f, or . That is, only one of those. For instance,

```
grepl("^[0-9_]+[.tif]$", "1234t")
# [1] TRUE
grepl("^[0-9_]+[.tif]$", "1234tt")
# [1] FALSE
```